# What is the benefit of NSScanner's charactersToBeSkipped?

Tags: cocoa, nsscanner

I have the string `@"    ILL WILL KILLS    "`, and I'm using NSScanner's `scanUpToString:intoString:` to find every occurrence of "ILL".  If it's accurate, it will `NSLog` 4, 9, and 14.

My string begins with 4 spaces, which I realize are members of the NSScanner's default `charactersToBeSkipped` NSCharacterSet.  If I set `charactersToBeSkipped` to `nil`, as in the example below, then this code accurately finds the 3 occurrences of "ILL".

```
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"    ILL WILL KILLS    "] ;
scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil ;
NSString* scannedCharacters ;
while ( TRUE ) {
    BOOL didScanUnignoredCharacters = [scanner scanUpToString:@"ILL" intoString:&scannedCharacters] ;
    if ( scanner.isAtEnd ) {
        break ;
    }
    NSLog(@"Found match at index:  %tu", scanner.scanLocation) ;
    // Since stopString "ILL" is 3 characters long, advance scanLocation by 3 to find the next "ILL".
    scanner.scanLocation += 3 ;
}
```

However, if I don't nullify the default `charactersToBeSkipped`, here's what happens:

- `scanner` is initialized with `scanLocation == 0`.
- `scanUpToString` executes for the 1st time, it "looks past" 4 empty spaces and "sees" `ILL` at index 4, so it immediately stops.  `scanLocation` is still `0`.
- I believe that I found a match, and I increment `scanLocation` by 3.
- `scanUpToString` executes for the 2nd time, it "looks past" 1 empty space and "sees" `ILL` at index 4, so it immediately stops. `scanLocation` is still `3`.

To me, it's a design flaw that `scanner` stopped at `scanLocation == 0` the first time, since I expected it to stop at `scanLocation == 4`.  If you believe that the above code can be rewritten to accurately `NSLog` 4, 9, and 14 without settings `charactersToBeSkipped` to `nil`, then **please**, show me how.  For now, my opinion is that `charactersToBeSkipped` exists solely to make NSScanners more difficult to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For now, my opinion is that `charactersToBeSkipped` exists solely to make `NSScanner`s more difficult to use.

Then you aren't very imaginative. The "benefit" of `charactersToBeSkipped` is to… wait for it… skip characters. For example, if you have a string like `@"   8   9 10 "`, you can scan those three integers using `-scanInt:` three times. You don't have to care about the precise amount of whitespace that separates them.

Given the task you describe, where you're just looking for instances of a string within a string, `NSScanner` is probably not the right tool. You probably want to use `-[NSString rangeOfString:options:range:]`.

The docs for `-scanUpToString:intoString:` are fairly clear. If `stopString` is the first string in the receiver (taking into account that `charactersToBeSkipped` will be skipped), then the method returns `NO`, meaning it didn't scan anything. Consequently, the scan location won't be changed.

The return value indicates success or failure. If the stop string is next (ignoring characters to be skipped), then there's nothing to scan "up to" the stop string; the scanner is already at the stop string, so the method fails.

Comment: You're right that `rangeOfString` is probably the better tool for my search for specific strings. I hadn't used `scanInt` before, but I see how it works well with the default `charactersToBeSkipped` and does not work with a `nil` `charactersToBeSkipped`.